# Linear Approximation of x/ (1-x)

Tags: linearization

I am trying to linearize the following function, but, having difficulties.

Let,

$x = \frac{l}{m},$

where $l,m \in R^+$ and $l<m$

Assume $l$ is a variable, while, $m$ is a constant (parameter), which makes $x$ a variable. I want to find a linear approximation for the following:

$f(x) = \frac{x}{2m(1-x)}$

In other words, as $2$ and $m$ are constant, I am interested in

$g(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$

I plotted the graph, but, it did not really help to derive something useful. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Linear Approximation? You want to approximate the function using a straight line?

Comment: Yes. Does it sound impossible?

Comment: Of course, it's possible, but the error may be large. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory

Comment: If you are looking for the usual calculus approximation, then it will be $h(x)=x$. This can be found by the formula $f(x)≈f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$ when $x≈x_0$.

Comment: @user496634 thanks for your comment. In my search for solutions, I confronted with the calculus approximation. Yet, I could not quite understand how it can make the function linear because the first derivative of the function still remains to be non-linear with squared $x$ terms. Additionally, I am lost with the term $x_0$. I am using this function in a MILP problem and I do solve for $x$ and other thousands of variables while there are several inequality constraints including $x$. If you may put your solution approach down, I will be thrilled to read it.

Comment: @user8028576 out of sheer curiosity, may I know what level of mathematics you are at? (Just starting Calculus I? Finished Calculus?) It may also help me produce an answer understandable to you and best addresses your problem.

Comment: I am a PhD student in industrial engineering with all qualitative sciences (business administration and literature) background and working experience in banking industry. Never taken a semester long calc class. I know operations research pretty well, but, when it comes to math side of it, I just hit the wall. I understood all you explained though. Thank you very much for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, over a range $a\leq x \leq b$, you want the best linear approximation $A+Bx$ of 
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{2m(1-x)}$$ the solution is to minimize the norm
$$F=\int_{a}^{b} \left(A+Bx-\frac{x}{2m(1-x)} \right)^2$$ with respect to parameters $A$ and $B$.

Integrating and then computing the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial F}{\partial  A}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial  B}$ and setting them equal to $0$ leads to two linear equations in $(A,B)$ 
$$2m(b-a) A + m (b^2-a^2)B+(b-a)+\log \left(\frac{1-b}{1-a}\right)=0$$
$$6m(b^2-a^2)A+4m(b^3-a^3)B+3 (b-a) (a+b+2)+6\log \left(\frac{1-b}{1-a}\right)=0$$ which you can simplify factoring $(b-a)$ in several places.
I let to you the pleasure of finding $A,B$ (but this is simple).

Around $x=0$, for $a=-b$, using Taylor series, we have
$$A=\frac{b^2}{6 m}+\frac{b^4}{10 m}+O\left(b^6\right)\qquad  B=\frac{1}{2 m}+\frac{3 b^2}{10 m}+\frac{3 b^4}{14 m}+O\left(b^6\right)\qquad F=\frac{2 b^5}{45 m^2}+O\left(b^7\right)$$

Taking an example using $a=-0.1$, $b=0.1$, $m=1$, this would lead to
$$A=\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+5 \log \left(\frac{11}{10}\right)+5 \log
   \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)\right)\approx 0.00167674$$
$$B=-150 (1+10 \log (3)-5 \log (11))\approx 0.503022$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for. Yet, I need some verbal explanation to digest all this and make it useful for my case. First of all, I use the function $f(x)$ in a mixed integer (non)linear programming model and $f(x)$ is the term that makes it non. Again, $0\leq x<1$. So, I guess, I need to set $a=0$ and possibly $b=0.999$ as close as to $1$. Then, instead of having my $x$ as a variable in my problem, I would have $A$ and $B$. But, I still need $x$ as a variable because I have to use in some other equality constraints. So, what would you recommend in this case?

Comment: Dr. Leibovici, if I understand your solution correctly with my limited math, I guess, you mean, I probably need to find $A$ and $B$ given that $a=0$ and (say) $b=0.999$. Then, plugging these in $f(x)=A+Bx$ will yield me an approximation of my original function, right? If I get it right until here, either this approximation does not really work or I miss something. I found $A=36.9472, B=-68.0547$ given that $a=0, b=0.999, m=1$. When I test the approximation with $x=0.6$, I get $f(x)_{approx} = −3.88562$ while $f(x)=0.75$. Furthermore, $f(x)\geq 0 $ must be held in any case.

Comment: @user8028576. Linearization of any function is local and valid over a small range.

Comment: Dr. Leibovici, so, do you mean $a=0$ and $b=0.999$ is a large range? If yes, how can I find the optimal range to make the approximation valid? I guess, I may create multiple equations of the above form with e.g., $a=0, b=0.1$, $a=0.1, b=0.2$ $...$ $a=0.9, b=0.999$. Right? But, is $0.1$ step size okay?

Comment: @user8028576. For each ("small") range, you need to compute $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help! I will compute them for every 0.1 step size and see how accurate my results are. If they are close enough, I will be so happy. Btw, though I did not know how to write the norm integration formulation, when I made the plot, minimizing the squared difference was what I was thinking in my mind. Once again, I appreciate your contribution.

Comment: @user8028576. This is equivalent to a linear regression using an infinite number of data points.

Answer (score 1):

I will present an elementary calculus solution. I will first rename your $g(x)$ into $f(x)$ because I can and because it looks nicer to the eye. It is apparent that the best linear approximation to any function at $x=0$ must be the tangent line to the function at $x=0$. In our case, since $f(0)=0$, our tangent line must pass through $(0,0)$ too and so it must be of the form $y=mx$. Since it is the tangent line, the gradient $m$ of this line must have the same "gradient" (i.e. rate of change) as $f$ at $0$. To find the gradient, thus, we set

$$ m = f'(0) $$

Where the RHS is the derivative at $0$; so the rate of change as previously mentioned. So now we just have to take the derivative of $f$ and evaluate it at $0$ to find $m$. I'm sure you know how to do this, but I'll put it here for completeness's sake:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{(1-x)-(-1)x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Evaluated at $0$ this is $1$. So $m=1$ and the closest linear approximation would be $y=mx=x$.

Comment: you basically propose $F = \frac{x}{2m}$ as a n approximation to the original $f(x)$ given in the post. If I get it correctly, this approximation is not any close to $f(x)$. Let $x=0.9, m=1$, $f(x)=4.5$ and $F=0.45$. If I interpret it wrongly, please let me know.

Comment: @user8028576 You are absolutely right that it is not a very good approximation. However, it is the best linear one, locally around $x=0$. This is unless, of course, you want to approximate it around a range around $x=0$, not just best at that point and it's "immediate vicinity". In that case, you can consider Leibovici's answer. You will see that in a small range immediately around $0$, my approximation is better; while in the range $a$ and $b$ in his answer his is generally better.

Comment: @user8028576 A helpful way to consider this is that my answer is the limit of Lebivoci's answer as $a$ and $b$ both approach $0$ (this is quite easy to prove). Around points extremely close to $0$, my approximation is extremely good; while his answer minimises the sum of the squared of the difference in values over a whole range $[a,b]$. One is an approximation at a point, the other is the approximation over a range.

Comment: @user8028576 I totally get the logic of both approximations. Your approximation draws a linear line starting from the origin and it does not really worry about minimizing the difference in the approximation and the actual. Your approximation is the easiest with a single $F=\frac{x}{2m} function. On the other hand, Leibovici's Taylor series draws a line for a "small" range of the whole plot that is as close as to the originial nonlinear line in that segmentation. Once I create "a lot of"of those lines with the given function, I will be able to approximate much more precisely.

Comment: But, when I get much closer to the tails of the approximation, his approximation yields an infeasible (negative) solution. For example, $a=0, b=0.1, m=1$, then, when I search for $x=0.0001$, it will give me $F\approx -0.00088$. Yet, this situation is understandable. To deal with it, I will adjust the ranges according to my expectations of the results. For instance, if I know $x=0.0001$ is an expected result, then I will add shorter ranges, which is equivalent of saying a decimal adjustment. I think, I got it! I am happy. Thank you very much to all, as you thought me something very useful!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac d{dx} \frac1 {1-x} = \frac1{(1-x)^2}$$ Additionally,
since $\frac1{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k$ clearly $$\frac1{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}$$Unfortunately, it does not really make sense to approximate linearly something like this in any global sense. Locally, evaluating $m = \frac1{(1-x_0)^2}$ would give you the slope of a line tangent to $\frac1{(1-x)}$ at point $x_0$ which locally approximates it linearly. I believe this is what you're asking.